# How to train a model with multiple inputs in a batch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a model like

```
inputA = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(40,40))
inputB = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=6)

a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(...)(inputA)
...
b = tf.keras.layers.Dense(...)(inputB)
combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([a, b])
....
```

It has 2 inputs, a preprocessed image, and some extra info.

My problem is to train more than one instance at a time. I have this train function:

```
def train_step(observations, actions, rewards):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = my_model(observations)
        loss = self.compute_loss(logits, actions, rewards)
    ....
```

In the line `logits = my_model(observations)` if I give just 1 sample it works, but if I send a list it gives the error "*Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 34 input tensors*".

I suspect I'm not passing the arguments correctly (it used to work when I had 1 input model).

How should I pass a batch of observations to this model?

To clarify:

- `observations` is a list of numpy arrays.
- `my_model(observations)` throws an error "*Layer model expects...*"
- `my_model([observations[0][0], observations[0][1]])` works
- `my_model([[observations[0][0], observations[0][1]],[observations[1][0], observations[1][1]]])` throws an error `Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 4 input tensors`.

I can just train using a call to `my_model([observations[i][0], observations[i][1]])`, in a loop (where `i` is my n-th observation in this batch. But I suppose that there will be performance issues if I do this compared to just send all the training batch in a call.

**EDIT**

To be more clear. I can:

```
input_a = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1, 40, 40, 3)).astype("int8")
input_b = np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(1, 6)).astype("int8")
logits = my_model([input_a, input_b])
```

This works perfectly.

But if I have more than one observation in a batch, I don't know how to pass the parameters:

```
input_a0 = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1, 40, 40, 3)).astype("int8")
input_b0 = np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(1, 6)).astype("int8")
input_a1 = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1, 40, 40, 3)).astype("int8")
input_b1 = np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(1, 6)).astype("int8")
logits = my_model([[input_a0, input_a0], [input_a1, input_a1]])
```

Throws:

```
ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 4 input tensors. Inputs received: ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the main problem that you've faced is to pass the input data correctly for the multiple inputs model. As you mentioned, `observations` is a list of `numpy` arrays, and you passed the data to a multi-input model as follows `my_model(observations)` - which seems problematic. What you probably need to do is to unpack the `observations` and pass the data as a `list`, e.g `my_model([input1, input2])`. Here is a possible solution.

**CustomFit**

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf 

class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        (x, z), y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self([x, z], training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

**Base Model**

```
import numpy as np

# Construct and compile an instance of CustomModel
inputA = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28))
inputB = keras.Input(shape=(32))

a = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputA)
b = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(inputB)
combined  = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([a, b])
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(combined)

# without custom fit 
# model = tf.keras.Model([inputA, inputB], outputs)

model = CustomModel([inputA, inputB], outputs)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])
```

**Train**

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(50, 28, 28)).astype("float32")
z = np.random.random((50, 32))
y = np.random.random((50, 1))
print(x.shape, z.shape, y.shape)

model.fit([x, z], y, epochs=3, verbose=2)
```

```
(50, 28, 28) (50, 32) (50, 1)
Epoch 1/3
7ms/step - loss: 19227.8789 - mae: 112.9769
Epoch 2/3
8ms/step - loss: 16268.3952 - mae: 98.0642
Epoch 3/3
10ms/step - loss: 14247.0742 - mae: 95.9225
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is not to unpack, but to send more than one multiple parameter at a time (a batch). Please, see my EDIT in the question.

Comment: How're you passing `*_b0/b1`? Also is it something you're looking for  `train_on_batch` functionality?

Comment: `train_on_batch` is level higher, I'm implementing a custom training function

Comment: Okay, let's start from the beginning with input pipelines and the model's input part. You defined a model with 2 inputs. So, it expects a data loader to give it 2 pairs of input. That is if your input pairs are  `(input_a0, input_b0)`  and the model would take only these two pairs because it is defined to take only two. But yes, the number of these pairs can be large, e.g. 10K, and we set `batch_size = 500` to complete in 20 steps.

Comment: Now, looking at the update, it looks like you wish to train many pre-initialized input pairs at a time with `fit`. Such as `my_model([[input_a0, input_a0], [input_a1, input_a1]])` - which is not correct. What would be appropriate in this context is to do: `for .. range(num_of_pairs): model.train_on_batch(each_pairs)` - Is it convincing?

Comment: Thanks @M.Innat The problem is solved: it was a kind of data packaging problem and your response made me aware of it. The problem was that the shape of my individual items was (1, x, y, 3) when it must be (x, y, 3) and then when aggregate all the batch it becomes (batch_size, x, y 3).

Comment: I see, glad to know. Don't forget to give a [hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA0Lo.png) >^-^<